# How to add a class to previous div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to add class to the first div before the "current" class.

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="current">Current</div>
<div ></div>
<div></div>
```

I just found out how to do it for the next div but still looking for solution to get the class before it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".current + div").addClass("prv");
});
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/0d7csqgb/2/

Do anyone know how I can do it?

//EDIT

Here's working solution if somebody need:
https://fiddle.jshell.net/df9ef0hf/6/

Comment: *"I just found out how to do it for the next div but still looking for solution to get the class before it."* There is no CSS-only solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `prev` function..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".current").prev().addClass("prv");
});
```

```css
.prv{
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>one</div>
<div>two</div>
<div class="current">Current</div>
<div>tree</div>
<div>four</div>
```

Comment: It works, thanks man! But one question I have, if the current class is the last div, can I have the first div as the next class? https://fiddle.jshell.net/0d7csqgb/4/

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see any changes here, can you update the fiddle?

Comment: see here: https://fiddle.jshell.net/mkdizajn/df9ef0hf/1/

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is, when I put the "current" class in the middle div for example, then .nxt doesn't work. Btw. it will be a carousel. https://fiddle.jshell.net/df9ef0hf/4/

Comment: I almost have it! I am looking for one thing. If the first div is current, then add .prv class to the last div. Can you help? https://fiddle.jshell.net/df9ef0hf/5/

Comment: this is it :) https://fiddle.jshell.net/mkdizajn/df9ef0hf/10/

Answer (score 4):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".current").prev().addClass("prv");
    $(".current").next().addClass("next");
});
```

```css
.prv{color:red;}
.next{color:green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>...</div>
<div>prv</div>
<div class="current">Current</div>
<div >next</div>
<div>...</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.current').prev('div').addClass('prv');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="current">Current</div>
<div ></div>
<div></div>
```